# SF Symbols lost color in iOS 15 widget

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget, widgetkit, sf-symbols

Multicolor SF symbols are black in iOS 15 widget. (have a look at the attached pictures 14.5 vs 15.0)

this is how it looks in the code:

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: getIconName(iconId: iconId))!)
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .frame(width: 20)
```

Playing around with `.renderingMode()` doesn't help. I've tried all posible params, but no luck. Only when I set it to .template and set some color, but I need it to be as it was - multicolor.

(It happens on both - iPhone and simulator (tested with beta iOS and beta XCode), I also tried to use new SF symbols, or apply new function available in iOS 15 `.symbolRenderingMode()` but nothing helped).

iOS 14:

[image: before]

iOS 15:

[image: after]

Comment: same problem for me on macos 12.beta5, xcode 13.beta5, target ios 15 and macCatalyst. Images in Views.
Probably another bug.

Comment: Try to replace the `Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: getIconName(iconId: iconId))!)` with `Image(systemName: getIconName(iconId: iconId))`, the native SwiftUI implementation of system images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## iOS 15+

The name of some of the symbols has been changed. Ensure that you use the correct name.

---

You need to use  `.symbolRenderingMode(.palette)` and set the color of each of its layers explicitly using `.foregroundStyle()` view modifier

```
         Image(systemName: "cloud.sun.fill")
                .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                .foregroundStyle(.black, .yellow)
```

Use

```
Image(systemName:getIconName(iconId: iconId))
```

instead of

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: getIconName(iconId: iconId))!)
```

Comment: combination of Image(systemName:getIconName(iconId: iconId)) and  .symbolRenderingMode(.multicolor) did the trick. thank you

Answer (score 0):

### iOS 16+

Maybe the solution by @mahan worked on iOS 15, but it didn't work for me on iOS 16+. I have found a working combination though:

1. `.symbolRenderingMode(.multicolor)`
2. It works only with `<IMAGE_ID>.fill` icons. If you try to use non-fill variant, it won't work.

Enjoy!

P.S. Note, that not all the SF icons have fill-version, so you might want to make sure it exists before displaying it.